# Adding a google map and polyLine to a google chart dashboard using Chartwrapper

Tags: javascript, google-maps, charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to add a polyLine to a google map that has been added to a google charts dashboard and has been ChartWrapper? I can easily put markers on the maps, but i can't seem to figure out how to add lines to the map? All of of the examples that I have found have created a polyLine using something like:

```
var linePath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: linePath,
      geodesic: true,
      map: myMap
    });
```

this doesn't seem to work if myMap has been created using:

```
var map1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
        'chartType': 'Map',
        'containerId': 'mapCont',
        'options': {
            'useMapTypeControl': 'true',
            'showTooltip': 'true',
            'mapType':'terrain',
            'showInfoWindow': 'true',

    });
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the option --> `'showLine': true`

from the [configuration-options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map#configuration-options)...

> `showLine` - If set to true, shows a Google Maps polyline through all the points.

see following snippet...

```
var map1 = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': 'Map',
    'containerId': 'mapCont',
    'options': {
        'useMapTypeControl': 'true',
        'showTooltip': 'true',
        'mapType':'terrain',
        'showInfoWindow': 'true',
        'showLine': true  // <-- show polyline
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and it is close, but doesn't quite do what I need. It seems that when I do this, and then add the 'lineWeight':'2', option, it will draw a polyLine between all the markers on the map. However, I want to add a polyLine that is independent of the markers that I already have on my map.

Comment: can you share a sample of the data?